# How to Alter Webforms Upload Ajax Callback?

Tags: webforms

When I hit the Upload button to load files, ajax is being triggered and alter my URL thus overwriting my $tid.

Hello I want to alter the webform actions after an ajax request so that I pass my $tid to that ajax callback like this:

```
$form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] = $tid;
```

I cannot find the upload webform ajax callback and how to alter it.

Thanks